# Does one location location ~* \.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ override a location ~* rule?

Tags: nginx

I don't have access to the nginx.config file but I need to serve webp images and increase the cache time at the same time. We had this rule in place and it was working perfectly:

```
location ~* \.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ {
    add_header Vary Accept;
    default_type image/webp;
    try_files $uri$webp $uri =404;
}
```

but after adding this rule, the webp images stopped being served:

```
location ~* \.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ {
    expires 365d;
}
```

Is it possible to combine both rules? I don't want to combine them and having the sites break since the person updating this file takes a while to respond.

My question is, will this work?

```
location ~* \.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ {
    expires 365d;
    add_header Vary Accept;
    default_type image/webp;
    try_files $uri$webp $uri =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be one `location` in a `server` block for any given string or regex. If there are two identical ones, only the first one will be used. Subsequent ones will never match and be ignored. But nginx does not warn about this.

So you *must* combine the desired directives in a single `location`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Combining everything into one location blocked worked.